# How is this C++ implicit conversion occurring?

Tags: c++, casting, implicit-conversion

Apologies in advance for this question. It's been awhile since I've used C++ and I can't seem to find an exact tutorial that answers my question. I **think** this is an example of implicit conversion, but I'm not sure.

#### Code:

```
class Square
{
public:        
    Square(int size) : size{size}
    {
    }

    int getSize() const
    {
        return size;   
    }

private:
    int size;
};

void doSomething(Square square)
{
    cout << "doSomething called with " << square.getSize() << endl;   
}

int main()
{
    // Should be passing in a Square type here, but instead passing an int.
    doSomething(23);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output:

`doSomething called with 23`

#### Questions:

1. Is this an example of implicit conversion?
2. How is this occurring? I'd be satisfied with a link that explains this in more detail. For what it's worth, I've already gone over [the cplusplus.com explanation of Type conversions](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/).

Thank you!

Comment: Make the constructor of `Square` [explicit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) and you will disallow the implicit conversion.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to understand why the conversion was occurring, but great to also learn a way to prevent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In brief: because `Square square = 23;` would be valid,  the call `doSomething(23)` matches the signature `doSomething(Square square)` ; that's how candidate function selection in overload resolution works.

If there were other overloads of `doSomething` that also matched the call, then the overloads would be ranked based on which conversions were required for each one.

The code `Square square = 23;` is valid because `Square` has a [converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain it fully!

Comment: If the constructor for `Square` were `explicit`, would this be a compilation error?

Comment: @Steve yes; an explicit constructor is not a converting constructor